# PHP - password_hash gives me different results with same values

Tags: php, authentication, password-encryption, password-hash

I'm making a register page for my website. I wanted to hash the password before send it to the database. Therefore, I used the **password_hash()** method. But this method gives different results with same password.

Here is my code;

```
    $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $hashedPassword2 = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    echo $hashedPassword. "   ------    ".$hashedPassword2;
```

And the result;
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9IEd.png)

I've tried **password_verify()** method just to make sure. It also says '**false**'.

```
$result =  password_verify($hashedPassword,$hashedPassword2);
echo var_export($result, true);
```

Here is the result;
[result-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3iH8.png)

Normally, It wouldn't be a problem for me. But I am going to need the similar process in my login page. What should I do? Should I try a different hashing method?

Comment: It's normal to get different hashes, because a random salt is included when hashing.

Comment: The first argument to `password_verify()` should be a plain password, not a hash.

Comment: `password_verify($password, $hashedPassword)`